# Is there an Ethereum wallet compatible with Mac OS X 10.7.5 or earlier?

Tags: wallets, ether, mac-osx, presale

I'm a non-techy newbie. I have a .json file relating to my presale Ether purchase which I am unable to access.

I downloaded the Ethereum wallet 0-7-6 for Mac, but unfortunately I only have Mac OS X 10.7.5 and I received a message saying the application needs Mac OS X 10.9 or later.

Is there any alternative wallet that I can use to access my presale Ether that would be compatible with Mac OS X 10.7.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the online wallets to transfer your presale Ether to [myetherwallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info)

there are also more options available, some of them are listed here:
[weusecoins.com/ethereum-wallets/](https://www.weusecoins.com/ethereum-wallets/)

Comment: Thanks Shayan. I've done the transfer using myetherwallet. It took me a while to realise that I didn't need to create a new wallet, but that I could open the original .json file using their system. I was also almost terrified to do anything in light of the recent phishing attacks. All sorted now.

Comment: Happy to help out, you could also download their source code and run it locally. when in doubt use Open source :)